# How to change css style based on value

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I have a boolean array that I am displaying in a razor foreach loop. Within the loop I am displaying the different values within the array. Is it possible,if so how, to change the css based on the value it is displaying?

For example

```
if (@status == true) THEN color = green; if (@status == false) THEN color = red.
```

Comment: Why not just add a class based on the status - `class="@(status ? "green" : "red")"`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you could add a data-attribute to the HTML element and alter the value (for example with Javascript) to/from "true/false" and use that in your CSS like so:

```
<element data-status="true">Content</element>
<element data-status="false">Content</element>

[data-status="true"] {
    color: green;
}
[data-status="false"] {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('.test').each(function() {
  if(parseInt($(this).css('font-size')) > 16) {
    $(this).css('color', 'green');
  }
});
```

```css
.test {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="test">Javascript manipulation: Green when largen than 16px</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question having the same problem, however I have implemented another solution, using c#/razor/css and no javascript. Someone might like this better.

**First**: define the possible values as an enumeration:

```
 public class enum MyRateTyp{
    Level1,
    Level2,
    Level3
  }
```

**Second:**
Find a place where, given the number on which the style will be based, the conversion will take place. In my case I added an extension method to the **int** type.

```
public MyRate Evaluate(this int i)
{
  MyRate answer = MyRate.Level1;
  if(i<50)
    {
      answer = MyRate.Level1;
    }
    .
    //All if statements here
    .
  if (i>100)
  {
    answer = MyRate.Level3;
  }
  return answer;
}
```

**Third:** On your **.css** file, define the style for each possible value, like so:

```css
.Level1{
     /*Style here for level 1*/
    }
.Level2{
   
      /* Style here for level 2*/
   }
    /*
      Other Styles here
    */
```

**Finally** On the Razor page, assign the extension method to the css class of the element you want to change the style based on the value.
For example.

```
The level is <p class="@(myInt_variable.Evaluate())"> @(myInt_Variable) </p>
```

Answer (score -2):

It is possible to change the color by putting an event on the box. This is done in javascript "AddEventListener"